# How to add data- attributes in Checkbox component via inputProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, checkbox, attributes, office-ui-fabric

I use Fabric components written in React + Typescript and when using Checkbox component I can add custom attributes such as `data-id` and so on - this is written also on documentation: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/checkbox

Whats the problem ? I do not know how to add one by passing it to `inputProps`.

Interface of React `HTMLAttribute` for field `data` require `string` value.

From what I see there interface of React's `HTMLAttribute` is generic one and Checkbox component passes this interfaces there: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/global.d.ts - They are empty.

Does somebody know how to implement the `data-` attributes there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases where an interface extends React.ButtonAttributes we filter out all the valid button props (aria included) and pipe them in. Seems this component never got updated to use that approach and is still using an older approach where we put all of those props into 'inputProps'.

```
  <Checkbox 
  label="Standard checkbox"
  inputProps={{'data-foo': 'bar'}}
  ariaDescribedBy={'descriptionID'} />
```

https://codepen.io/micahgodbolt/pen/djNGQv